# Set values using a case statement

Tags: sql

Table `Rate`:

```
Fees | Region  | Rate
-----+---------+---------
 A1  | Intra   | 0.00015   
 A2  | Intra   | 0.000325   
 A3  | Inter   | 0.000025   
 A4  | Inter   | 0.015
```

Table `Amount`:

```
Region | Amount | A1 | A2 | A3 | A4
-------+--------+----+----+----+----
Intra  | $10    |  ? |  ? |  ? |  ?
Intra  | $11    |  ? |  ? |  ? |  ?
Inter  | $12    |  ? |  ? |  ? |  ?
Inter  | $13    |  ? |  ? |  ? |  ?
```

Any help will do, I am struggling to write the case statement that will update table using the different rates in table 1.

I have tried:

```
Update a
set A.A1 = Amount * R.Rate
from dbo.Amount as A 
inner join dbo.Rate R where R.Region = A.region
```

I want the rate applied to be the Rate A1 and Region to be inter/Intra depending on the Region in Amount table

```
Update a
set A.A2 = Amount * R.Rate
from dbo.Amount as A 
inner join dbo.Rate R where R.Region = A.region
```

I want the rate applied to be the Rate A2 and Region to be inter/Intra depending on the Region in Amount table)
etc

Please help

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is one way of doing it

```
Update a
set 
A.A1 = Amount* R1.Rate
,A.A2 = Amount* R2.Rate
,A.A3 = Amount* R3.Rate
,A.A4 = Amount* R4.Rate
from dbo.Amount as A 
inner join dbo.Rate R1 
on R1.Region = A.region and r1.fees = 'A1'
inner join dbo.Rate R2 
on R2.Region = A.region and r2.fees = 'A2'
inner join dbo.Rate R3 
on R3.Region = A.region and r3.fees = 'A3'
inner join dbo.Rate R4 
on R4.Region = A.region and r4.fees = 'A4'
```

Answer (score 1):

I gather this is how your tables are related.

```
update Amount
set
    A1 = Amount * (select Rate from Rate where Region = Amount.Region and Fees = 'A1'),
    A2 = Amount * (select Rate from Rate where Region = Amount.Region and Fees = 'A2'),
    A3 = Amount * (select Rate from Rate where Region = Amount.Region and Fees = 'A3'),
    A4 = Amount * (select Rate from Rate where Region = Amount.Region and Fees = 'A4')
```

One of the advantages of using subqueries is that you'll get an error if you return more than one row. There are reasons to avoid the `update ... from ...` syntax. Based on the sample data it appears you're going to have nulls so you'll want to use `outer join` rather than `inner join` if you do choose to do it that way.